# How to configure a service daemon file for a Golang program

Tags: go, service, daemon

**This is the service file for php**, it works well

```
[Unit]

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env php /path/to/server.php

[Install]
```

**this one is for python**

[Unit]

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/server.py

[Install]
```

**When I try this for Golang it's not working, what's wron**g?

```
[Unit]

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/go /path/to/server.go
Environment=GOPATH="/home/test/go"

[Install]
```

Comment: Maybe because your command is wrong? in order to run go program you should use `go run /path/to/gofile.go`

Comment: I tried that too, here is the error  `Process: 22784 ExecStart=/usr/bin/go go run /home/testbed/Desktop/test/test.go
 Main PID: 22784 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`

Comment: Your command is still wrong, `go go run /path/to/file.go` is wrong.

Comment: `go run/path/to/file.go` is not working either

Comment: still wrong `go run file.fo`  not `go run/file.go` `go` is an executable `run` is a command compile and run you program `file.go` is a golang script.

Comment: the extension of a golang file is `go` or `fo` ?  I think it's .go

Comment: I ran this `ExecStart=/usr/bin/go run /home/testbed/Desktop/test/test.go

Environment=GOPATH="/home/testbed/go"`  it showed an error

Comment: this one is not working too `Process: 28203 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env go run /home/testbed/Desktop/test/test.go
 Main PID: 28203 (code=exited, status=127)`
`

Comment: Why you pretend an `/usr/bin/env` whats the point? Are you sure `/usr/bin/go` is available ? Why you want to use `run` instead of compile to executable ?

Comment: go doesn't exist in `bin` there is only env, php and java

Comment: when I do `go env` I see this
 ` GOENV="/home/testbed/.config/go/env"

GOEXE=""

GOFLAGS=""

GOHOSTARCH="amd64"

GOHOSTOS="linux"

GOINSECURE=""

GONOPROXY=""

GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/testbed/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64" `

Comment: `whereis go` command shows this  `go: /usr/lib/go /usr/local/go /usr/share/go /usr/local/go/bin/go`   so I don't know which one is ok

Answer (score 1):

It worked after trying every single output from `whereis go` 
this is the conf file for Golang:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/go/bin/go run /home/testbed/Desktop/test/test.go
```

Answer (score 1):

Python and PHP are interpreted languages which means they need to be run through program called interpreter (for PHP that's `/usr/bin/php` and for Python  `/usr/bin/python`) which takes source code (your `.php` or `.py` file) and interprets it (translates source into machine code understood by computer as it runs). So anyone who wants to run your program needs:

1. your program (source code `.py` files)
2. any libraries you used
3. interpreter

Golang isn't like that, it is compiled language (like C or C++) instead. In case of compiled languages you have a program called compiler which takes source code (your `.go` file) and produces (compiles) binary file directly understood by any computer of same class (having same or compatible CPU, OS, etc.) without need of any interpreter or compiler. In Golang for most cases also all libraries you use are also compiled in into that binary making it super convenient and easy for users.

In Golang, rather than using `go run` command which is shortcut for compile and execute once. You want to finish your coding, then compile program using `go build` command into an executable form (on Windows that's `.exe` file and on Linux that will be binary - executable file without extension) and then execute that from your service file.

Let's suppose your code file is `server.go`:

1. `go build -o server server.go` will compile your source and produce executable called server (we forced `go build` command to name it `server` by adding `-o server`)
2. You can run `./server` as many times as you want.
3. If you need to update code then you also need to re-run `go build -o server server.go` and that will generate updated binary. Which is slightly different than in PHP or Python (so be wary of this).

Then you just update your service file (see `go` not needed at all):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/server

[Install]
```

Compiling code from service file is not good idea as it requires go installed on machine that runs program. Also in Golang programs often pull libraries from Github and if someone changes library so your program doesn't compile anymore service won't run.